# Changing border color of \frame{}

Tags: graphics, color, framed

I am using the `\frame{}` command to draw a box around an image, like `\frame{\includegraphics{...}}`. Is there a way to change the color of this box? It is black by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\frame{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}}
\textcolor{red}{\frame{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Short and to the point, thank you!